# Perl LibXML: isSameNode method

Tags: perl, libxml2

I'm trying to compare two nodes using 'isSameNode'.  However, one of the nodes is created via 'parse_balanced_chunk'.  From the http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-isSameNode document, is says "This method provides a way to determine whether two Node references returned by the implementation reference the same object."

So I'm wonder is it not working as I would expect because they are indeed coming from two different sources (one from the parsed txt file, the other from parse_balance_chunk)?

Here is the 'test_in.xml' & code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TT>
 <A>ZAB</A>
 <B>ZBW</B>
 <C>
  <D>
   <E>ZSE</E>
   <F>ZLC</F>
  </D>
 </C>
 <C>
  <K>
   <H>dog</H>       
   <E>one123</E>       
   <M>bird</M>       
  </K>
 </C>
</TT>

use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new({keep_blanks=>(0)});
my $dom = $parser->load_xml(location => 'test_in.xml') or die;

#called in scalar context ($na1)
my ($na1) = $dom->findnodes('//D');
my ($na2) = $dom->findnodes('//D');
my $X1 = $na1->isSameNode($na2); ##MATCHES

my ($frg) = $parser->parse_balanced_chunk ("<D><E>ZSE</E><F>ZLC</F></D>");
my $X2 = $na1->isSameNode($frg); ##WHY NO MATCH?

my ($na3) = $frg->findnodes('//D');
my $X3 = $na1->isSameNode($na3); ##WHY NO MATCH?

print "SAME?: $X1\n";
print "SAME?: $X2\n";
print "SAME?: $X3\n";
```

And the output:

```
SAME?: 1
SAME?: 0
SAME?: 0
```

So the first 'isSameNode' test obviously MATCHES (same exact findnodes & xpath expression).
But neither of the 2nd or 3rd 'isSameNode' tests work using the node from the 'parsed_balance_chunk'.  Is it something simple I'm overlooking with the syntax or is it just that I can't compare two nodes this way?  If not, what is the method for comparing two nodes?  Waht I'm ultimately trying to determine if a block of xml code (i.e. from a previous parsed_balance_chuck) already exist in the xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they're not the same node. Like the name says, it checks if two nodes are the same node. You seem think think it checks if two nodes are equivalent, but that's not what it does.

Comment: I appreciate your response, but I need some clarification.  You say $na1 & $na3 are not equivalent due to whitespace, but I thought the whitespace for $na1 has been nullified by the fact that I'm using keep_blanks=>0 ?  In fact when I print out the 'textContent' for each node, the values are exactly the same. So what would you suggest then to compare two nodes?

Comment: oops, I missed keep_blanks. Fixed.

Comment: Re "what would you suggest then to compare two nodes?" `$n1->toString eq $n2->toString`?

Comment: @ikegame - thank you!... I know your 'toString' suggestion might sound trivial to many folks, but to me at least it helps a lot, so I really appreciate your advice.  Using your advice, the approach I'm taking is that I'm going to grab all the xml file nodes (i.e. - //*), run each node thru a foreach loop and 'toString' test it against the parsed_balance_chunk node.  This works great!!  Originally I thought I could get around using a foreach loop, but it appears that's the only way I can check & compare if a parsed_balance_chunk node already exist in a file.